# Can Ruby call methods or procs like c calls functions?

Tags: c, ruby

I am pretty new to Ruby. I am college and just did a programming course that covered regular c. My final project for class was a slop intercept project, which was fairly easy, but i had to use functions for everything, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int get_problem(int *choice){
  do {
  printf("Select the form that you would like to convert to slope-intercept form: \n");
  printf("1) Two-Point form (you know two points on the line)\n");
  printf("2) Point-slope form (you know the line's slope and one point)\n");
  scanf("%d", &*choice);
  if (*choice < 1 || *choice > 2){
      printf("Incorrect choice\n");}
  }while (*choice != 1 && *choice !=2);
  return(*choice);
}
...
int main(void);
{
  char cont;
    do {

  int choice;
  double x1, x2, y1, y2;
  double slope, intercept;
  get_problem (&choice);
...
```

I have several more functions completing the entire program. I got a new job and i need to start learning Ruby, So for my first project I wanted to convert this program into Ruby, now I was able simply get rid of the functions and just run it without methods or procs. I wanted to know if it is possible to do the same thing, define a method, then call the method without giving an input, but getting back the variables stored in the method. Would it be possible using methods or procs. Here is a little of what i have so far using a proc.

```
get_problem = Proc.new {
begin
puts "Select the form that you would like to convert to slope-intercept form: "
puts "1) Two-Point form (you know two points on the line)"
puts "2) Point-slope form (you know the lines slope and one point)"
choice = gets.chomp.to_i
if (choice < 1 || choice > 2)
    puts "Incorrect choice"
    end 
end while (choice != 1 && choice !=2)
}
....
begin
get_problem.call
case choice
when 1
    get2_pt.call
    display2_pt.call
    slope_intcpt_from2_pt.call
when 2
    get_pt_slope.call
    display_pt_slope.call
    intcpt_from_pt_slope.call
```

Now I know I probably have it all wrong, but I figured I would give it a shot. I have it as methods before where I had

```
def get_problem(choice)
....
end
....
get_problem(choice)
....
```

Is there something basic I am missing? As you can see, i used pointers in c and had to initialize the variables in the main.

Thank you for taking the time to help me out.
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a pointer to a variable in Ruby, but I don't think you need to do that to accomplish what you're trying to do. Try this:

```
def get_problem
  puts "Select the form that you would like to convert to slope-intercept form: "
  puts "1) Two-Point form (you know two points on the line)"
  puts "2) Point-slope form (you know the lines slope and one point)"

  loop do
    choice = gets.chomp.to_i
    return choice if [1, 2].include? choice
    STDERR.puts "Incorrect choice: choose either 1 or 2"
  end
end

choice = get_problem
puts "The user chose #{choice}"
```

This defines a method `get_problem` which loops until the user chooses either `1` or `2`, and returns their chosen number, which you can store in a top-level variable `choice`.

Comment: thank you for that, I think that will help when i have one variable, but for my next function, i have 4 variables, would it be similar?

double get2_pt(double *x1, double *x2, double *y1, double *y2){
do{
printf("\nEnter the x-y coordinates of the first point separated by a space: \n");
scanf("%lf%lf", &*x1, &*y1);
printf("\nEnter the x-y coordinates of the second point separated by a space: \n");
scanf("%lf%lf", &*x2, &*y2);
....
return(*x1, *x2, *y1, *y2);
}

Comment: well that stinks, i cant enter it looking like code in comment, but you get the point, that is my c function getting 4 variables from them.

Comment: I figured it out, in the method calls i did (x1, y1, x2, y2) = get2_pt and if they had to send a variable i did display2_pt(x1, y1, x2, y2). then in the method just reciprocated the variables coming in and put return values.